# Kubuntu 12.10 Shortcut to Restart X Server?

Tags: shortcut-keys, kubuntu, restart, xserver

I have just upgraded from Kubuntu 12.04 to 12.10.

Until now, I was using <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>PrintScreen</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> key combination to restart the X Server.

After the last upgrade this shortcut doesn't work anymore.

Do you know if there is any new key combination to restart the X Server?

An online search did not return any obvious results as 12.10 is not very popular since it hasn't been released yet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**The old way**

KDE System Settings > Input Devices > Keyboard;Advanced tab "Key sequence to kill the X server"

[image]